# JDBC Connection failing with ORA-12505 on Win8, Oracle 11g XE

Tags: jdbc, oracle-xe, tns

I'm having an error that goes beyond what I see in [TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

I'm using Windows 8, Oracle 11.2 XE, java 1.7.15, and Eclipse Juno SR2.

The error I receive is:

*java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor*

I have the driver registered properly, and I've edited the listener.ora to make the service explicit, in both ways I've seen given as exampled - under SID_LIST_LISTENER, I added:

```
(SID_DESC =
   (SID_NAME = XE)
   (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
)
```

and under LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST I added

```
(DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
 )
```

tnsnames.ora contains, as its first entry:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

The source code making the calls is:

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521/XE";
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "myuser", "myuserpw");
```

I've also been through the following permutations on the connectionString. with results noted here:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE // java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:XE  // error ORA 12505
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE // error java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE // error ORA-01017
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE // error ORA-01017
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: The first of your connection strings is what I normally use.  It works for me to connect to Oracle 11g XE on Windows 7.  ORA-01017 indicates to me that your database is up and running but the authentication details you've provided to connect to it are not valid.  Silly question perhaps: are you sure that the username and password are correct?

Comment: Yes, I've tried several permutations of username and password, including SYSTEM out of frustration.

Comment: I have an Answer! Although since I don't have enough StackOverflow points, I can't post it for another 8 hours, here it is in comments:  


(Bloody-minded stubbornness is its own reward, I guess)

I changed which Connection call I made and restructured the connection string thataway, as in:

    String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:myuser/mypw@localhost:1521:XE";
    myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

THAT works! Now the next guy can Google it....

Answer (score 2):

I have an Answer! (Bloody-minded stubbornness is its own reward, I guess)
I changed which Connection call I made and restructured the connection string thataway, as in:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:myuser/mypw@localhost:1521:XE"; 
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

THAT works! Now the next guy can Google it. The version of the call with three parameters blows up every time I try it, but the same fundamental string with the username/pw embedded works in the single-parameter call.

I believe this is a bug in the driver provided with the XE database - oh Oracle, will you let us know?

Comment: Odd - I couldn't reproduce this.  I used Windows 8 x64, JDK 1.7.0_17 32-bit and Oracle XE 11g 11.2.0.2.0, and connected successfully using the first of the URLs in your list.  Still, glad to see you sorted your problem out.

Comment: It may be a byproduct of the corporate laptop I get to program on - some interesting "lockdown" options they've set up. Perhaps if I was running as admin, it wouldn't be an issue. Hmmm... Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 0):

OPEN `cmd`

execute the `lsnrctl` command.

Type `start` in the `LSNRCTL>` prompt.