# Error while connecting jdbc to the oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

i get the error while connecting my jdbc program to the oracle from last 3 days i tries to solve this problem using the online solution which i got from the google but it cant solve my problem this is my code for sqlplus connection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ex","system","12345");
        System.out.println(con.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(e instanceof SQLException){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           System.out.println(e.toString());
   }
  }
}
```

error that i got while compile the from with the command prompt and my listener.ora file is look like this

my oracle version is **Version 11.2.0.2.0**

### my jdbc driver version is **ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0**[image: this is the status of mylistener which i got with<code>>lsnrctl stat</code>]

[image: error while compile the java program]

[image: my listener.ora file look like this]

**this is my listener.log file while i compile the program with the command prompt**

```html
Wed Jan 27 08:40:20 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:40:20 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ex)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=Jagdish))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=52366)) * establish * ex * 12505
TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
Wed Jan 27 08:40:32 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:40:32 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:41:34 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:41:34 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
27-JAN-2016 08:41:36 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:43:23 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:43:23 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:45:11 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:45:11 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:46:57 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:46:57 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:48:44 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:48:44 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:50:30 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:50:30 * service_update * xe * 0
27-JAN-2016 08:50:31 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:51:30 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:51:30 * service_update * xe * 0
27-JAN-2016 08:51:36 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:52:18 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:52:18 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:54:05 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:54:05 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:55:01 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:55:01 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:55:31 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:55:31 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:55:52 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:55:52 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:57:41 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:57:41 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 08:59:28 2016
27-JAN-2016 08:59:28 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 09:01:16 2016
27-JAN-2016 09:01:16 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 09:01:37 2016
27-JAN-2016 09:01:37 * service_update * xe * 0
Wed Jan 27 09:03:03 2016
27-JAN-2016 09:03:03 * service_update * CLRExtProc * 0
Wed Jan 27 09:03:27 2016
27-JAN-2016 09:03:27 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ex)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=Jagdish))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=52658)) * establish * ex * 12505
TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

**and i tried to solve this error usin the following link which i found while googler**

[solution which is from the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

[coderech solution](http://www.redstonecontentsolutions.com/technical-blog/tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor-error-message-of-the-monthjanuary)

[another solution which i got from the stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

but finally all and all my work i cant able to resolve this problem please if anyone know the soltion the please give the solution it's to usefull for me please and thanks in advance.....hope to get answer

Comment: have u tried replacing 1521:ex with 1521/ex? probably issue may be with jdbc string that you are using.

Comment: are you solved the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have your instance/SID the wrong way around (ex). It should read:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","system","12345");
```

Comment: sorry sir its not working for me i already have tried for that and after your answer i am try it again but its not solving my problem i have windows 10 installed on the computer is there any problem with it?

Comment: try Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","12345"); or Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/12345@127.0.0.1:1521:xe");

Comment: Recommendation is to use the long form connection URL  
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))

Easy Connect URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/myorcldbservicename