# Jasper iReport: SQL problems: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DatabaseName

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, ireport

[image: Jasper iReport error]

Hi,

if you are struggling with this issue

*"Jasper iReport: SQL problems: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DatabaseName"*

or with the issue from picture above in Jasper iReport,

enjoy your saved time, because here's the solution:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

Comment: Hi. No it's not. You could never figure this particular issue out on that page.

Comment: But it does, and better than your answer.

Comment: How and where on that page you can make a conclusion, that you need to  rewrite your JDBC URL connection because some process could change it after you did set it?

Answer (score -1):

[image: Solution]

The problem is simply in **JDBC URL**.

Even though you might put it right at first, 
it could be changed to default after importing an *.jar file, etc.

So just change this URL, and it should be working.

The path to change JDBC URL:
 1. click on Datasources (white-blue icon),
 2. pick the connection you are currently working on,
 3. Modify,
 4. And change your JDBC URL.