# JDBC Thin connection string in Oracle uses both colon and forward slash

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I wanted to know can we use both colon and forward slash with SID in making the connection URL in Oracle?

e.g.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<SID>
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521/<SID>
```

Will these two are same and will work?

I am building an application which will work with both Oracle RAC and non RAC environments and RAC environments supports **SERVICE NAME** with `forward slash` so wanted to check will `non RAC` environment support `forward slash` .

For `RAC` environment URL is like this

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521/<SERVICENAME>
```

**Update** 
This is different question because i want to ask is it possible to use both (`:` and `/` while using `<SID>` in the connection String which we call as `OracleJDBCUrl` .

Comment: @JSapkota so it means with <SID> in `non RAC` we can use both colon and forward slash if SQL Developer is saying connection established and status is success?

Comment: However, if I try to connect from Java, '/' is used for service name and ':' is used for SID.

Comment: [Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)

Comment: @JSapkota  can i use anything(between colon and slash) while using the <SID> ?

Comment: @DeepakJain This isn't a URL. It's a JDBC connection string. It's syntax is defined in the documentation. JSapkota already provided a link to a duplicate answer *and* the docs. Why do you want to use `/SID` when you see that the syntax is `:SID` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using Service Name instead of SID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to use because I'm able to connect to the DB by using `/` also so which one is correct, I am stuck to that point. and URL i meant for the `OracleJDBCURL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used both colon `:` and forward slash `/` for SID in `connection URL` and was able get the connection established.
I think in `Oracle 11g` to connect with a `Service Name`,  we can only use the forward slash `/` .

Answer (score 1):

We recommend to use the long form of the connection URL as show below.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))

Check out [DataSourceSample](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionManagementSamples/DataSourceSample.java) and [UCPSample](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/ucp/ConnectionManagementSamples/UCPSample.java) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Both SID and ServiceName works for me using only "/". I'm using Java.sql.Connection on windows server, I'm not sure if it works on Linux.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>/<SERVICENAME or SID>
```

Answer (score 0):

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME

for instance:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.80.12.162:1624/xyzabc
```