# Oracle Database Service not working after changing tnsname.ora and listener.ora

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle19c

I have installed oracle database on Virtual (windows guest)and tried to connect to it via JDBC from host machine. Since the listener listens only to local host I changed the ip from local host to the ip address of the virtual machine itself . After the altering the tnsname.ora and listener.ora the services stopped and i could connect to it.
TNSNAME.ora file

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.24.255.55)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.24.255.55)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

LISTENER.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleApp)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\OracleApp\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.24.255.55)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Output of lsnrctl service before altering the above file ie host = local host

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 28-MAR-2023 12:41:52

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "39497c8ffac84c17938bc17b28d587ef" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:3 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:3 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:3 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: DESKTOP-U6PKHQ7, pid: 8072>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-U6PKHQ7)(PORT=49773))
Service "orclpdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:3 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

After changing the host to ipaddress

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 28-MAR-2023 12:46:14

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.24.255.55)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Any help will be really helpful Thanks

Comment: Off-topic really, but you probably need to [change the database's `local_listener` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769396/266304). (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267276/266304); or you could [listen for both addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746373/266304)...)