# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist?

Tags: java, oracle

I am using
Oracle

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jun 25 20:17:54 2020
```

Java

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

jar files

```
ojdbc14.jar

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
```

I have created a table in my oracle dbms

```
SQL> create Table employees ( name varchar(20));
Table created.
```

I inserted few records

```
SQL> insert into employees (name) values ('Navjot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into employees (name) values ('jagjot');


SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

I trying to fetch these records from my java class But it says no such table exist.

BaseDAO.java

```
import java.sql.*;

    class BaseDAO
    {
        public Connection getConnection()
        {
            String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe";
            String user="system";
            String password="system";
            Connection conn=null;
            try
            {
                Class.forName(driver);
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
                System.out.println("Connected to oracle database successfully");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            return conn;
        }//End of getConnection method
    }//End of BaseDAO class
```

**RetriveAllEmployees.java**

```
import java.sql.*;
public class RetriveAllEmployees extends BaseDAO
{
    public void retrive()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn=getConnection();
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from EMPLOYEES");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String employeeName=rs.getString("name");
                System.out.println(employeeName);
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RetriveAllEmployees retriveAllEmployees=new RetriveAllEmployees();
        retriveAllEmployees.retrive();
    }
}
```

**When I tried to execute this code it says table does not exist**

```
   E:\aman\java\jdbc\jdbc 1 doc examples\003 connection oracle sql>java -classpath .;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar; RetriveAllEmployees
Connected to oracle database successfully
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

**When I login to oracle through command line**

```
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:system

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL> conn sys as sysdba;
Enter password:none
Connected.
```

Comment: It's impossible to establish connection to the DB. Check your connection properties (above all JDBC url)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. '"It's impossible to establish connection to the DB. " @AngeloImmediata. As you can see when I complile my cod it says connected to database successfuly. BaseDAO

Comment: In the previous version of the question (before the edit) the error message was: **The Network Adapter could not establish connection** that's why i wrote that comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check who is the owner of the table: the owner of the table is the user having run `CREATE TABLE`.

You can access a table without owner prefix only if you connect as table owner  (or if a synonym has been created): if the table has been created with `SYSTEM` user, you need to connect as `SYSTEM` user - you can with another user but to access the table you need to use `SYSTEM.EMPLOYEES` and to have SELECT privilege on `SYSTEM.EMPLOYEES` (which you cannot have by default unless you connect with DBA role or with `SYS AS SYSDBA`).

ORA-00942 means either table does not exist or you don't have any privileges to access the table.

Comment: I did. But now the error message says `java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
localhost:1521:xe`

Comment: See detailed steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript.